# Chrome's remote debugging - inspect window closing on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, inspect

I'm trying to open Inspect WebView in chrome DevTools, i can see my device and the opened WebView, but when i click on the inspect link, the DevTools window opens for a brief moment and autoclose immediately.

Chrome version is   48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by upgrading to Version 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit)